# What is the purpose of the 'Pdf embedded' option of the Static Text element in iReport 5.6.0?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Does anyone know what the 'Pdf embedded' option in Text properties of the Static Text element's attribute is used for in iReport Designer 5.6.0?

[image]

Comment: The font would be embedded at the pdf file. [Font embedding](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-fonts.html)

Comment: @Alex K , Thanks for your reply, now I got it.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: "The font would be embedded at the pdf file." - What it is the best practice? Embed or not?

Comment: And what is the difference if you embed? Is the font file copied inside the PDF? In which cases would you do that? Is it safer to embed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question just today. But I took a look in the official page bellow, and the Summary says:

> Unless you are okay with your PDF potentially being rendered with a default/native PDF specification font, or unless you are confident your client machines will always have the fonts installed, you need to use the "embed..." checkbox while creating your font extension

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/what-purpose-embed-font-pdf-document

Because the font is needed in others clients to render correctly.

PS: sorry my English..